# Arithmetic, Geometric and Harmonic prove equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a, b, c, d$ be in Arithmetic Progression, $a, e, f, d$ be in Geometric Progression, and $a, g, h, d$ in Harmonic Progression respectively; prove that $ad=ef=bh=cg$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a,b,c,d$ are in Arithmetic Progression, we have
$$c+a=2b,d+b=2c\tag1$$

Since $a,e,f,d$ are in Geometric Progression, we have
$$af=e^2,ed=f^2\tag2$$

Since $a,g,h,d$ are in Harmonic Progression, we have
$$\frac 1a+\frac 1h=\frac 2g,\frac 1g+\frac 1d=\frac 2h\tag3$$
From $(1)$, we have
$$b=\frac{2a+d}{3},c=\frac{a+2d}{3}\tag4$$
From $(2)$, we have
$$f=(ad^2)^{\frac 13},e=(a^2d)^{\frac 13}\tag5$$
From $(3)$, we have
$$h=\frac{3ad}{d+2a},g=\frac{3ad}{2d+a}\tag6$$

From $(4)(5)(6)$, we have
$$ef=(a^3d^3)^{\frac 13}=ad,$$
$$bh=\frac{2a+d}{3}\cdot\frac{3ad}{d+2a}=ad,$$
$$cg=\frac{a+2d}{3}\cdot\frac{3ad}{2d+a}=ad.$$